# SQL/Firebird 3. Как одним простым SQL-запросом убрать дублированные значения по столбцу?

Tags: sql, select, firebird, table, null

Применяю оператор `SELECT DISTINCT` по нескольким столбцам. Там, где значения строк двух и более столбцов разные, появляются дубли (по одному столбцу).

Вот, что я имею ввиду, см. на картинке::
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дубли не нужны! 
Конечно, можно потом в цикле пройтись по выборке и заменить все повторяющиеся в столбце значения на NULL.. Но, (код обработки на ЯП) - это может быть очень медленно!

И Вот, как сразу написать такой SQL-запроc, который только одно первое значение строки по столбцу покажет, а остальные такие же повторные значения строк сделает NULL?? На SQL

P.S. Конечно, в идеале это должно работать и по нескольким столбцам тоже..

Comment: *одно первое значение строки по столбцу* Понятие первого значения появится только после того, как будет указан критерий сортировки, по коему эти самые абы дубли уникальны. Пока я такого критерия (да и вообще упоминания сортировки) не наблюдаю.

Comment: Это надо делать не в БД, а уже при выводе данных. Подавление повторяющихся значений имеет смысл только на экране, а о экранном выводе БД думать не должна. Поэтому SQL не рассчитан на решение таких задач. Оно конечно наверняка решается, но обычно очень громоздко и/или медленно. Достаточно легко отделаетесь, если firebird поддерживает оконную функцию lag()

Answer (score 1):

Это лучше делать при выводе данных, но если уж очень хочется...

```
SELECT
  NULLIF(t.field1,LAG(t.field1) OVER(ORDER BY t.field1,t.field2)),
  t.field2
FROM table1 AS t
ORDER BY t.field1,t.field2
```

LAG, как и прочие оконные функции, доступна начиная с версии Firebird 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, если разобраться, тут может помочь группировка по этому столбцу, удаление существующей таблицы и вставка на её место сгруппированой. Посмотри примеры, там есть и другие подходы. https://toster.ru/q/90425
Если совсем ничего не поможет, а хочется сделать именно средствами SQL просмотри в сторону PL/SQL . Напиши функцию.